# Get all values from a specific kendo grid column

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json, kendo-grid

I need get all data from one column of a kendo grid, I've searched a lot but didn't found something useful. I create a kendo grid based on a JSON coming from API `API/LogService/ReadAllLog`. I'm using AngularJS anyway.

#### My code:

```
$scope.gridColumns = [{
  field: "SystemName",
  editable: false,
  title: _t("Title.SystemName"),
  allownull: false,
  width: 100
}, {
  field: "FormName",
  editable: false,
  title: _t("CommonTitle.SystemFeatureForm"),
  allownull: false,
  width: 100
}]
```

and then I fill it like this:

```
$scope.gridConfig = {
  autoBind: true,
  inlineOperationalUrl: {
    read: {
      url: webAccess + "api/LogService/ReadAllLog",
    }
  }
};
```

and this is my grid in my view (**note:** `pn-gridview` is a custom directive created from angular grid view with some changes):

```
<pn-gridview id="SystemsGrid"
      config="gridConfig"
      columns="gridColumns"
</pn-gridview>
```

Comment: How do you create your grid (dataSource)? Please add some codes and a minimal example of what you got.

Comment: What type of data is `api/LogService/ReadAllLog`?

Comment: it's from a MongoDB database.

Comment: Yea, but what type of data is it? JSON, XML, .. ?

Comment: it's a list of a .net class

Comment: Could you please add a minimal set of the data returned by `api/LogService/ReadAllLog`?

Comment: as I said it's a method that returns a list of class that contains two fields named systemname and formname.

Comment: yea, please add those as an example in your questions please. `list of class` is not a datatype.

Comment: Please add the data returned by `api/LogService/ReadAllLog` and not the class code iteself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146996/discussion-between-efarzad-and-lin).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Collect all values on one column with a simple helper function:

```
function getColumnValues(selector, columnName) {

  //Init
  var columnData = [];
  var data = $(selector).data("kendoGrid").dataSource._data;

  //collect each valueof given columnName
  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (typeof data[i][columnName] !== "undefined") {
        columnData.push(data[i][columnName]);
    }
  }

  //return column data as array
  return columnData;
}
```

#### > [DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/linlin/r1skwxw3/)

In your case you need to call this helper function like:

`var myColumnData = getColumnValues('#SystemsGrid', 'SystemName');`

---

#### You can access a specific **row** data with:

`var myRowData = $("#SystemsGrid").data().kendoGrid.dataSource.at(index);`